# How to sequence along different values in an object (or vector) for one observation-year compared to another observation-year?

Tags: r, for-loop, sequence

I am attempting to identify households in a panel dataset who may have had income that increased from one year to the next. I wrote a loop code in R that has all the income variables within one object/vector and I want to “sequence along” this object/vector to determine if, starting with the 1st variable in this vector, the value in the subsequent variable is greater than the preceding variable, and if so, create a new variable using ifelse(). My main issue is how to identify the next variable in sequence and I’m not understanding why it can’t be “i+1” when referencing subsequent variables (see code below).

```
income_vars <- c("Income2010","Income2011","Income2012","Income2013",
                 "Income2014","Income2015","Income2016","Income2017",
                 "Income2018","Income2019","Income2020")

income_up_num <- setNames(numeric(11), names(income_vars))


#Loop 1 Try
for (i in seq_along(income_vars)){
  income_up_num[i] <- ifelse(income_vars[i] < income_vars[i] + 1,
                                              1, 0)
}


ERROR: Error in income_vars[i] + 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator



#Loop 2 Try
for (i in seq_along(income_vars)){
  if ( i == "NA"){
      income_up_num == "NA"    
    }else if (i < i+1){
      income_up_num == 1
    }else{
      income_up_num == 0
 
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Nabi :-) . It would be very helpful to know what your input data, eg Income2010 is. It helps reproduce the problem when the post includes a data set.
An effective way to include one is `dput()`.
Run dput, then paste the output into your question.
See [rdocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput).
If your object is a vector, matrix, table, or data frame and is large,
`object |> head() |> dput()` will help give manageably sized output.

Comment: `ifelse(income_vars[i] < income_vars[i] + 1` I suspect you meant to be `ifelse(income_vars[i] < income_vars[i + 1] ` As is, you are adding 1 to a vector of characters, hence the error about the binary operator (+). You'll have to fix your loop counter as your last loop will be i = 11, and it will try and access 11 + 1 to the right of <, which doesn't exist.

Comment: `income_vars` is a vector of characters (the variable names) and you are comparing the names with < not the variables.

Comment: Hi Isaiah, great point about the loop counter to make sure it doesn't go beyond my vector length of 11. This is what I finally ended up with: 
```
`#11 variables 

for(i in 1:11-1){ 
more_income <- ifelse(Income_vars[,i] < Income_vars[,i+1], "Y", "N") } table((more_income))` 
```
ETA: Thanks for the heads up on the dput()!